# Passing settings from Reusable Block to it's children

Tags: block-editor

I have a following situation:
I'm using reusable blocks to easily manage data in tables that repeat couple of times around the page. I created a setting with 2 controls: Toggle to say if this element should show in submenu, and text field to store a submenu label.

```
function addBlockAttribute(settings, name) {
if (typeof settings.attributes !== "undefined") {
    settings.attributes = Object.assign(settings.attributes, {
        showInSubmenu: {
            type: "boolean",
        },
        submenuLabel: {
            type: "string",
        },
    });
}
return settings;
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
"blocks.registerBlockType",
"awp/cover-custom-attribute",
addBlockAttribute
);
```

I want to keep using the reusable blocks, but I need the submenu settings to be separated (I don't always want this table to show in submenu).

Is there any way to detect whether my block is inside of the reusable block, or to stop one field from being copied to all of the other reusable blocks?